# brew list failed with the error: Device error @ io_fillbuf - fd:7

Tags: homebrew

My system is macOS High Sierra 10.13.2. when I run *brew list*, I get an error:

```
$ brew list
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': Device error @ io_fillbuf - fd:7 /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build_environment.rb (Errno::EDEVERR)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/readall.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/tap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/compat/tap.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/compat.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `brew doctor` ?

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub The same as above error:
$ brew doctor
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': Device error @ io_fillbuf - fd:7 /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build_environment.rb (Errno::EDEVERR)
......

Comment: Just run brew update-reset,It works.

Comment: post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run brew update-reset,It works.